# Counting inside a recursive function

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

```
int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension) {
static int count = 0;    

for(int i = -(static_cast<int>(std::floor(radius))); i <= static_cast<int>(std::floor(radius)); i++) {
    point.push_back(i);

    if(point.size() == dimension){
        if(isPointWithinSphere(point, radius)) count++;
    }else countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension);

    point.pop_back();
}

return count;
}
```

I have the above recursive function for which I would like to increment some variable if the condition `isPointWithinSphere( ... )` is true. My initial approach was to declare a static variable called `count` so that it maintains the count through each recursive call. OK, this works fine for when I call the function `countLatticePoints` the first time, but now if i call the function again it adds to the previous `count` value when i first called `countLatticePoints`. I understand that this happens because of the way that the static qualifier behaves. Is there any way that I can reset that `count` variable back to 0 after one call finishes before I call the second one ? I don't want to use global variables of course, is there any other approach that can work in this situation ?

Comment: You don't need to pass native types, like `double` or `int` as `const &`. Const-reference is usually used to pass big objects or classes

Comment: "this works fine for when I call the function countLatticePoints the first time, but now if i call the function again it adds to the previous count value when i first called countLatticePoints." - if this is not the behaviour which you want, WHAT DO YOU WANT?  After the fuction called from the outside first time and returned, what should be your count?  After it was called the second time and returned, what should be your count?

Comment: @user31264 After first call it is 19, second call should be 51 but instead its 19 + 51

Comment: _Is there any other approach that can work in this situation?_  Yes, absolutely! You don't need recursion to create your permutations. See my answer to your earlier question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37326790/224704

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any static variable or additional parameter. Here is what you need.

```
int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension) {
    int count = 0;
    const int iRadius = std::floor(radius);
    for(int i = -iRadius; i <= iRadius; i++) {
        point.push_back(i);
        if(point.size() == dimension){
            if (isPointWithinSphere(point, radius))
                count++;
        } else
            count += countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension);
        point.pop_back();
    }

    return count;
}
```

On a side note, you don't need to pass int or double as reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper function to accomplish what you want as follows:

```
void countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension, int& count) {
    const int int_radius = static_cast<int>(std::floor(radius));
    for(int i = -int_radius; i <= int_radius; i++) {
        point.push_back(i);

        if(point.size() == dimension){
            if(isPointWithinSphere(point, radius)) count++;
        }else countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension, count);

        point.pop_back();
    }
}

int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension) {
    int count = 0;    
    countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension, count);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass **count** as a parameter; give it a default value of 0, so the initial call doesn't have to supply it.  Will that do for your needs?

Comment: In your situation it returns 0 for the first call, I tried this already.

Comment: When you tried this, did you pass count by reference?

Comment: @0x5453 i'm using this `int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension, int count = 0)`

Comment: count should be passed by reference if you want the value to be modified outside of the function, i.e. `int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double &radius, const int &dimension, int& count)`.  You can't give it a default value in this case; just make sure you set count to zero when calling the function for the first time.

Alternatively, you could set the value of count when returning from the recursive call, i.e. `}else count = countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension);`.

Comment: @0x5453 the problem with count being passed by reference is that If i call the function again it adds to the current value of count. So if after the first call count is 19 then the second call will start count from 19

Comment: This is the right answer. Obviously you need to pass count in the recursive call and assign its result to count itself: `count = countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension, count);`.

Comment: I see. Below is my answer.